# How do i integrate google wallet in my application

Tags: android, android-pay

I want to integrate google wallet in my application: 
I need the below functionality:-

1. User can buy some coins from merchant application using google wallet .
   For e.g. User will be given an option that  10 coins -- 1$.
   so user will be redirected to his google wallet and payment of 1$ will be done from his google wallet to Merchant application's wallet.
2. User can redeem the coins to money in his google wallet . < This will be done automatically once the user's coin count reaches a predefines value say 1000.> So As soon as user's coins reach 1000. They will be converted to dollars and will be added in his google wallet.

As i did some research :

Google Wallet is available on Android in two flavors.

In-app Billing - used to sell digital goods:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Instant Buy for Android - used to sell real goods and services:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/android-overview/

I do not understand which one of the two serves my purpose.

Please guide me . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this question.
I needed to integrate In-app-billing. I declared my products on google developer console. And user can buy the products using in app billing service.

For Redeeming , google does not support peer to peer payment processing . So my application can not give money directly from merchant account to user account using google service . Google does not support it .
I needed to integrate Paypal for sending money to user account from merchant account.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the two will serve your purpose fully, as neither will allow your second scenario (selling coins back for real money).

- **In-app billing** will let your user buy coins and pay via the Play Store.
- **Instant Buy (Android Pay)** is just a payment method you can use. You'll still need a payment processor (e.g. Stripe or Braintree). The payment processor may allow your second scenario as well, but this will not be handled by Android Pay.

There is no way to pay to a user's Google Wallet. Google Wallet can only be used to send money to friends and family, not for conducting any business. This functionality existed in the past, but is now fully integrated and rebranded into Android Pay (Instant Buy).